# Running batch file with subprocess.call does not work and freezes IPython console

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, ipython, spyder

This is a frequent question, but reading the other threads did not solve the problem for me.
I provide the full paths to make sure I have not made any path formulation errors.

```
import subprocess    
# create batch script
myBat = open(r'.\Test.bat','w+') # create file with writing access
myBat.write('''echo hello
pause''') # write commands to file
myBat.close()
```

Now I tried running it via three different ways, found them all here on SO. In each case, my IDE Spyder goes into busy mode and the console freezes. No terminal window pops up or anything, nothing happens.

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\\Users\\felix\\folders\\Batch_Script\\Test.bat'], shell=True)


subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\Users\\felix\\folders\\Batch_Script\Test.bat'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)


p = subprocess.Popen("Test.bat", cwd=r"C:\\Users\\felix\\folders\\Batch_Script\\")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Each were run with and without the `shell=True` setting, also with and without raw strings, single backslashes and so on. Can you spot why this wont work?

Comment: check line endings are `\r\n` instead of just `\n` as it's needed by the windows shell. May want to also call `@ECHO off` to cleanup output with `subprocess.run`.

Comment: Line endings setting in Spyder is `CRLF` which is correct, right? I had the same problem with other commands, without echo.

Comment: idk... write the file then open it with notepad++ and view hidden characters to check. It could be locale dependent... I had to fix it

Comment: Ok, I can confirm it is `echo helloCRLFpause` so this seem to be correct and not the cause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spyder doesn't always handle standard streams correctly so it doesn't surprise me that you see no output when using `subprocess.call` because it normally runs in the same console. It also makes sense why it does work for you when executed in an external cmd prompt.

Here is what you should use if you want to keep using the spyder terminal, but call up a new window for your bat script

`subprocess.call(["start", "test.bat"], shell=True)`

[`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) Starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command. You need `shell=True` because it's a cmd built-in not a program itself. You can then just pass it your bat file as normal.

Comment: You, Sir, are a hero. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have solution of your problem :)

don't use `subprocess` instead use `os`

Example :

```
import os
myBatchFile = f"{start /max} + yourFile.bat"
os.system(myBatchFile)
# "start /max" will run your batch file in new window in fullscreen mode
```

Thank me later if it helped :)

Comment: What is start? It says undefined for me, is there something missing? Do you mean `myBatchFile = "start /max" + "Test.bat"` ? This does not work for me. I get syntax errors for your code if I dont adjust it like that.

Comment: You can use os.system() if you dont mind it not being attached into anything

Comment: @BenMoskovitch I did that already, as this fix was obvious. Doesnt solve the undefined "start" command though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Felix "Start" will start that batch file in new window in Windows, and thats totally optional i also recommended him os as you said

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use with open()...

   with open(r'.\Test.bat','w+') as myBat:
   myBat.write('echo hello\npause') # write commands to file
2. I tested this line outside of ide (by running in cmd) and it will open a new cmd window

   subprocess.Popen([r'Test.bat'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

Comment: In cmd window this works for me, too. However, not from IDE. Do you have any idea what could cause this? Spyder 5.1.5 here ...

Comment: @Felix standard stream redirection (stdout, stdin, stderr) for IDE's is very complicated, and spyder 5.2.0 has made some improvements, but this still does not work in the latest version.